# How to loop through a list and print numbers greater than 50 in Scratch?

Tags: mit-scratch

I have written a script to prompt the user to enter values between 30 and 100. Now I want to print all the number greater than 50 in the list when the user presses the space bar. I am confused on how to go through the list and print numbers greater than 50. Can someone give me hint?

This is what I have so far:

[image: Screenshot of Scratch script]

The program works till I press space key. It doesn't run after that.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this was late, but it seems like you are not incrementing your index value after every iteration.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQphB.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Disagree with the bot here, @stonefish points out the exact issue that's keeping the code in the example from working.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

[image: scratch code]

Replace "list" with the name of your list, and make sure to change the wait time to something more preferable.

Comment: Can you check the image i added to my question?